# How to generate javadoc for some codes with persian characters?

Tags: maven, intellij-idea, javadoc, maven-javadoc-plugin

There are some values for some fields which are hardcoded in my project. when I add maven javadoc plugin to my pom file, after "maven clean install" it gives the error :

```
unmappable character for encoding Cp1252
[ERROR] *?????º???? ?ª????????????????
```

Is there any way that javadoc doesn't give error for that?

Note: I have added this one to plugins:

```
              <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-javadoc-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.10.4</version>
                <configuration>
                <charset>UTF-8</charset>
                    <docencoding>UTF-8</docencoding>
                </configuration>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>attach-javadocs</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>jar</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally I found the solution: One should add encoding to javadoc plugin configuration.

```
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-javadoc-plugin</artifactId>
    <configuration>
        <encoding>UTF-8</encoding>
    </configuration>
```